# How to exclude row from CSV with Papaparse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, papaparse

I have a CSV file and I used Papaparse to parse my data from it to a table in HTML.
But I would like to exclude a row from my file;
This is how it's written the CSV file:

```
"Name";"Email";"Telephone"
"[Lista] E.D. Elettronica Dedicata";"";""
"Andrea Ferrari";"andreaferrari@ed-elettronica.it";"15"
"Claudio Podavite";"claudiopodavite@ed-elettronica.it";"20"
"Cristiano Mascheretti";"cristianomascheretti@ed-elettronica.it";"13"
....
```

And I would like to exclude the second row:

> "[Lista] E.D. Elettronica Dedicata";"";""

I cannot do it manually from the file because it's automatically created.
I tried look at other question or the dock, but I only found out about header change header and not exclude row

This is how I form my table on HTML from JS (I took it from [here](https://github.com/namieluss/csv-datatable-papaparse)):

```
function htmlTableGenerator(content) {
    let contatti = document.getElementById('contatti');

    let html = '<table id="contactsTable" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" style="width:100%">';

    if (content.length == 0 || typeof(content[0]) === 'undefined') {
        return null
    } else {
        const header = content[0];
        const data = content.slice(1);

        html += '<thead>';
        html += '<tr>';
        header.forEach(function(colData) {
            html += '<th>' + colData + '</th>';
        });
        html += '</tr>';
        html += '</thead>';
        html += '<tbody>';

        data.forEach(function(row) {
            if (header.length === row.length) {
                html += '<tr>';
                row.forEach(function(colData) {
                    html += '<td>' + colData + '</td>';
                });
                html += '</tr>';
            }
        });

        html += '</tbody>';
        html += '</table>';
        // insert table element into csv preview
        contatti.innerHTML = html;
        // initialise DataTable
        initDataTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you simply be able to slice from row 2? `const data = content.slice(2);` (see [slice() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice))

Comment: Oh actually yes. It did it, thanks.

Comment: I'm still new to JS so didnt know how to work around the code it took.

Comment: Sure no problem - I added an answer as well for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Slice the array from index 2

If you want to ignore the line after the headers, change this line:

```js
const data = content.slice(1);
```

to this:

```js
const data = content.slice(2);
```

There is no shame in reading the documentation for code you don't understand - especially if you don't understand. Here is the documentation for "slice":

[JavaScript: Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: You saved me! And you are also very kind, thnks!

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing?

Comment: Sure - but you can also ask a new question if it's something bigger.

Comment: Okay! Let's see, in case I'm gonna create a new one. In my CSV file It parse also email. Is there a way to set `<a class='link' href='mailto: **EMAIL**>` so that when someone click on it it make it possibile to send email?

Comment: Well the E-Mail is on index 1 of the dara, correct? Look up the [documentation for Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). It tells you the function can take a second parameter of the index. Instead of `row.forEach(function(colData) {` you would write `row.forEach(function(colData, index) {` and check for `index === 1` to print the E-Mail link. There are other ways but this seems easiest for you.

Comment: Okau. I'm gonna give a look at the doc you link me. Thanks you so much for your time!